# multiple datepicker shows same value in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have implemented multiple datepicker in reactjs, 
when i click add, will add new row and on delete will delete row.
I have `additionalFields` in home.js represents value of date to be shown in row
but when i add row, new row fields should be empty.

```
home.js
 additionalFields: [
        {
          pickdate: new Date("Jan 1, 2019"),
          starttime: "",
          endtime: "",
          id: 0
        },
        {
          pickdate: new Date("Feb 1, 2019"),
          starttime: "",
          endtime: "",
          id: 1
        }
      ]
```

Datepicker, timepicker should show pickdate,starttime and endtime value.But on running code, it shows first array value for all rows.
here is code https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-pond-qgt5o

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly is not working?

Comment: @timotgl datepicker and timepicker should show the values of additionalfields, but it shows the firstarray values to all rows, thats was the issue